# Transpose dataframe columns based on a column's value - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
    param       per     per_date    per_num             
0   XYZ         1.0     2018-10-01  11.0                
1   XYZ         2.0     2017-08-01  15.25               
2   XYZ         3.0     2019-10-01  11.25               
3   MMG         1.0     2019-08-01  15.71               
4   MMG         2.0     2020-10-01  11.50               
5   MMG         3.0     2021-10-01  11.75               
6   MMG         4.0     2014-01-01  14.00
```

I would like to have an output like this,

```
 param per_1  per_2   per_3   per_4 per_date_1 per_date_2 per_date_3 per_date_4 per_num_1 per_num_2 per_num_3 per_num_4
0 XYZ   1      2       3       NaN  2018-10-01 2017-08-01 2019-10-01 NaN        11.0      15.25     11.25     NaN
1 MMG   1      2       3       4    2019-08-01 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2014-01-01 15.71     11.50     11.75     14.00
```

I tried the following,

```
df.vstack().reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=0)
```

This is not giving me the output I need.

If you see, I have `per` column that has incremental values that can go into column names when I transpose them.

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last flatten columns names by `f-string`s:

```
df = df.set_index(['param', df.groupby('param').cumcount().add(1)]).unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  param  per_1  per_2  per_3  per_4  per_date_1  per_date_2  per_date_3  \
0   MMG    1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0  2019-08-01  2020-10-01  2021-10-01   
1   XYZ    1.0    2.0    3.0    NaN  2018-10-01  2017-08-01  2019-10-01   

   per_date_4  per_num_1  per_num_2  per_num_3  per_num_4  
0  2014-01-01      15.71      11.50      11.75       14.0  
1         NaN      11.00      15.25      11.25        NaN
```

Comment: Quick elegant answer. Silly question, how do I google a question like this? I could not find resources online. Any advise?

Comment: @user9431057 - Hard question, not idea.

Comment: What if I have `XYZ` under param continuously? Without `MMG`? In this case, I do not need `groupby` correct?

Comment: @user9431057 - ya, if always only one unique value `XYZ` then not, then use `df.set_index(['param', append=True]).unstack(0)`